# Python Logging always print message on console without reason

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have a code that work but do things that I don't understand.
This code use `logging` python module. The problem is that when I run this script there is always (in additional of the normal Stream Log) a line on the console that I don't want (the second line in STDOUT at the bottom of this post).

I don't understand why this line exist and how solve this problem.

I think that problem is due to the usage of `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` but I need to use it because if I don't use it `logger.info('This is a INFO-01')` don't work just the level WARNING, etc ... I tried several things but that just produced errors and don't find answer on Internet.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file07.log')
c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

c_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)


logger.info('This is a INFO-01')
```

STDOUT:

```
2021-12-11 17:54:30,203 - INFO - This is a INFO-01
INFO:__main__:This is a INFO-01
```

If someone can help me, I will be really grateful.
Cordially

Comment: You're using `basicConfig()` which adds a Handler and then you add more handlers manually. No wonder you get lines more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed it right. Take a look at [this image](https://docs.python.org/3/_images/logging_flow.png) from the documentation.

By default the propagation is `True`. So *your* `logger` object has a parent logger named "root".

`basicConfig` essentially does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a `StreamHandler` with a default Formatter and adding it to the root logger.

The 'root' is the parent of all loggers. So after your `logger` logger's handlers process the message, it will get handed to the parent logger's handlers, and because it has a handler now, it outputs that message for the second time with the default format.

You can remove that because you don't need it. Don't forget to specify LEVEL for your `logger`: (I removed the `f_handler` handler in the below code)

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # <----- here

c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

c_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)

logger.addHandler(c_handler)

logger.info('This is a INFO-01')
```